# Is it possible to turn off SQL highlighting in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

It seems like IntelliJ is expecting strings to be escaped by the quote-char and not a backslash. Is there a way to change the SQL dialect here, or how can I get rid of the error squiggly in my editor?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can right-click in the editor and select Change Dialect:

[image]

More details at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-languages-sql-dialects.html.